# Bar Chart with variable width of bars

Tags: r, width, bar-chart

I'm trying to create some type of barchart/histogram where the width of the bar is dependent on two columns.  s1 = Start Time s2 = Stop Time.  My x axis is 24 hours from midnight to midnight.  So, if one row as s1 = 12:00 AM s2 = 1:45 AM then the bar will go from 12:00 am to 1:45 AM and if the next row is s1 = 2:00 AM  s2 = 2:30 AM that the bar will be more narrow than the first since it only goes for 30 minutes compared to the 1.75 hours in the first bar.  Then the height is dependent on a third column Value which is continuous data as well.  If there is another visualization I am open to that as well.  There should be no overlap between times, but if there was having the bar(s) transparent/a pattern to show there's some overlap would be helpful.

Below is a small amount of data similar to what I'm using

```
             s1     |        s2         |  Value
 1/1/2018 12:00 AM  | 1/1/2018 1:45 AM  |  10.2
 1/1/2018 2:00 AM   | 1/1/20182:30 AM   |  3.1
```

Comment: And how do you want to deal with overlapping bars?

Comment: erocoar I just updated the question.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
dat <- data.frame(start = c("1/1/2018 12:00 AM", "1/1/2018 2:00 AM"),
         stop = c("1/1/2018 1:45 AM", "1/1/2018 2:30 AM"),
         value = c(10.2, 3.1))

dat$start <- strptime(dat$start, "%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p")
dat$stop <- strptime(dat$stop, "%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p")

lower <- as.POSIXct(strftime(min(dat$start),"%Y-%m-%d"))
upper <- as.POSIXct(strftime(as.Date(max(dat$start))+1,"%Y-%m-%d"))-1
limits = c(lower,upper)

ggplot(dat) + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = dat$start, xmax = dat$stop,
                ymin = 0, ymax = dat$value), alpha = 0.8, color = "black") +
  scale_x_datetime(
    date_breaks = "2 hour", 
    date_minor_breaks = "1 hour",
    labels = date_format("%H:%M", tz = "CET"),
    limits = limits)
```

[image]

If you have no overlap and/or the y describes categories, you could consider `geom_dumbbell` in the `ggalt` package. For a lot of data, you could also consider `geom_horizon` (same package)

Comment: Why not just use `geom_bar(... aes(width=...` which allows an explicit width argument?

Comment: I think the `width` argument there can't be specified separately for each bar?

Comment: I wasn't sure how to specify the width especially on a time scale @smci, and `geom_bar` just calls `geom_rect` anyways

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work! Approach is to reshape the data so that there is one value per time, including adding zero values in between times. Then you can just use `geom_step` to plot. This is not really a "barplot" per se, because they are supposed to be for categorical data. Your data looks more like a continuous time series with no values at particular locations, so we just have to construct the right data for that series.

I think the steps to add the rights rows feel more convoluted than they ought - if anyone has improvements to suggest feel free!

```
    library(tidyverse)
tbl <- tribble(
  ~s1, ~s2, ~value,
  "1/1/2018 12:00 AM", "1/1/2018 1:45 AM", 10.2,
  "1/1/2018 2:00 AM", "1/1/2018 2:30 AM", 3.1
) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(s1, s2), lubridate::dmy_hm) %>%
  gather("s", "datetime", s1, s2) %>%
  arrange(datetime)
tbl_1 <- tbl %>% bind_cols(id = group_indices(tbl, value))

tbl_2 <- tbl_1 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(datetime = last(datetime)) %>%
  mutate(s = "s4", value = 0) %>%
  bind_rows(tbl_1, .)
full_tbl <- tbl_2 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(datetime = first(datetime)) %>%
  mutate(s = "s0", value = 0) %>%
  bind_rows(., tbl_2) %>%
  arrange(datetime, s)

print(full_tbl)
#> # A tibble: 8 x 4
#>      id datetime            s     value
#>   <int> <dttm>              <chr> <dbl>
#> 1     2 2018-01-01 00:00:00 s0     0   
#> 2     2 2018-01-01 00:00:00 s1    10.2 
#> 3     2 2018-01-01 01:45:00 s2    10.2 
#> 4     2 2018-01-01 01:45:00 s4     0   
#> 5     1 2018-01-01 02:00:00 s0     0   
#> 6     1 2018-01-01 02:00:00 s1     3.10
#> 7     1 2018-01-01 02:30:00 s2     3.10
#> 8     1 2018-01-01 02:30:00 s4     0

ggplot(data = full_tbl) + geom_step(aes(x = datetime, y = value))
```

[image]

Comment: Related: [Stacked bar chart to show process development over time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262056/stacked-bar-chart-to-show-process-development-over-time)